# Django getting properties of model dynamically

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like

```
class Document(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
```

Document objects are listed in a template as

```
{% for doc in doc_list %}
    {{ doc.comment }}
    {{ doc.upload_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I'd like to reach the properties of `doc` dynamically like

```
{{ doc."comment" }}
```

or

```
{{ doc|getField:"comment" }}
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "dinamically"? What would you expect to get if you could do `{{ doc."comment" }}`? What would you like to be the difference between this and `{{ doc.comment }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to access fields on a model by using another variable, which you don't necessarily know at the time. So you might have `some_var` be passed into the template, and this is the field in the model that you'd like to display, such as comment or upload_date.

You could build a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to do this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_model_attr(instance, key):
    return getattr(instance, key)
```

Now in your template you can do stuff like:

```
{% for doc in doc_list %}
    {% get_model_attr doc "comment" %}
    {% get_model_attr doc some_var %}
{% endfor %}
```